# What does \n mean

Tags: php, function

I am trying to understand somethings in a function to do with `\n`. Here is what I see/have and just wanting to know what the `\n` are for.

```
$s = "<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" border=\"0\">\n<tr>\n";

foreach($lang['abrvdays'] as $day) {
    $s .= "\t<td class=\"column_header\">&nbsp;$day</td>\n";
}

$s .= "</tr>\n\n";
return $s;
```

I do know that it is to get the names of the days on a calendar. I have a calendar I built which I use

```
 {
 <tr>
   <th>
      This is where my names of days go.
   </th>
 </tr>
}
```

And would like to use the code above. But when I do, it has 7 `<td>` cells across the top and is the same height as all other `<td>` cells. I tried changing the `<td>` to `<th>` still doesn't work.

Comment: It means a new line (line break)

Comment: "\n" This works (results in a newline):                                    
'\n'This does not result in a newline:

Comment: It's used for prettified HTML source output here. It has little to do with how the table is rendered or cells are sized. Look into CSS for adapting it.

Comment: Not adding `\n` at the end of a line's code or to split up elements, would render your code in one long line in HTML source. I.e.: 
`<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0"><tr><td class="column_header">Output from variable in here.</td>` instead of one underneath each other. Look at your HTML source, with and without the `\n` and you will see the differences.

Comment: Btw, what you asked is considered as two questions. Ask one at a time, not two. Your first about the `\n`, could have easily been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Adds a new line in the output of the script.

Comment: @MightyPork do not insult people

Comment: I just find it pathetic that you go so low, as to answer this, to gain some rep points. Sorry if it offended you.

Comment: He asked, I answered. That's so simple.

Comment: @MightyPork Sorry dude when learning like to know. Guess you knew everything form the get go

Comment: @user1236784 nah, but I used Google when I didn't know something. Asked only after having found nothing useful.

Comment: Adds a new line if the OS is UNIX-based (Windows does not recognize \n, on Windows it's \r\n).